# Find $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the system of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

\begin{cases} (-1+i)z_1+(2i-3)z_2=-2; \\ (2+2i)z_1+(3+5i)z_2=0. \end{cases}

I decided by the method of Cramer. Received such an answer:
$$
z_1=-\frac{3 + 5i}{2} \;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\; z_2=1+i
$$

Can you please tell me how to find $ z_1 $ and $ z_2 $ without Cramer's method?

Comment: `without Cramer's method` Eliminate $\,z_2\,$ between the equations. For example, multiply the first one by $\,3+5i\,$, the second one by $\,2i-3\,$, then subtract the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left(-1+i\right)\cdot\text{z}_1+\left(2i-3\right)\cdot\text{z}_2=-2\\
\\
\left(2+2i\right)\cdot\text{z}_1+\left(3+5i\right)\cdot\text{z}_2=0
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, we can write $\text{z}_1=\text{a}+\text{b}i$ and $\text{z}_2=\text{c}+\text{d}i$. We also know that the imaginary parts of the LHS of the system has to be 0. So we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
-\text{a}-\text{b}-3\text{c}-2\text{d}=-2\\
\\
\text{a}-\text{b}+2\text{c}-3\text{d}=0\\
\\
2\text{a}-2\text{b}+3\text{c}-5\text{d}=0\\
\\
2\text{a}+2\text{b}+5\text{c}+3\text{d}=0
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Solving that system gives $\text{a}=-3$, $\text{b}=-5$, $\text{c}=2$ and $\text{d}=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitution is another method you can use. Substitute value for $z_2$ from second equation in first equation. $$z_2=\frac{-(2+2i)}{(3+5i)}z_1$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: plug $$z_2=\left(-\frac{11}{34}+\frac{7
   i}{34}\right)z_1$$ into your first equation and solve this equation for $$z_1$$
HINT: $$-\frac{2+2i}{3+5i}\cdot \frac{3-5i}{3+5i}=...$$

Comment: You might want to explain where you got $(-11+7i)/34$.

Answer (score 0):

Let$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1+i & -3+2 i \\ 2+2 i & 3+5 i\end{bmatrix}.$$Then your system is equivalent to$$A.\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$Therefore, you can solve it doing\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}&=A^{-1}.\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2}+\frac{5 i}{2} & \frac{3}{2}-i \\ -1-i & -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}-3-5i\\2+2i\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}